# kubuntu 15.04 plasma 5.3 how to stop session timeout from logging out

Tags: kubuntu

At the moment, sddm will logout the session on expiry.
It is different to the way kde worked.
2 things: I am unable to locate where to specfiy the session timeout value and secondly, how to change the action from logout to say lock screen.
Issue is I often have long running processes then get bumped off with the forced logout.

Answer (score 15):

I encountered the same problem.

I found: 'System Settings' -> (Workspace)-'Desktop Behavior' -> 'Screen Locking'.

Comment: Thanks for that. Actually, it seems that in 'System Settings > Power Management > Screen Energy Saving > Switch off after 5 mins', does indeed switch off the screen. But there seems no way back to re-enabling or re-activating SDDM short of rebooting the system. I can get Linux consoles up after switching the screen back on but not SDDM via Alt-F7 or any other way apart from rebooting.